# How to open word files in browser, on new tab, instead of automatically downloading

Tags: html, file, browser, download, tabs

There is a word document to be accessed with the href="link"

Clicking the link automatically downloads the document instead of opening on new tab.

I have tried to set target="_blank", but it is not helping